# construct a binary matrix such that each column contains only single "1" and sum of each row is of desired value

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I want to construct a binary(0s and 1s) matrix satisfying the following constraints:

1. Each column must contains only single binary 1 and rest elements of that column are 0s.
2. The sum of each ROW of matrix should be a desired value.
   For example, given a `rowSum` vector of [5 7 6 8 .......] then the sum of first row should be 5, sum of second row should be 7 and so on.
3. `nCol`==`Sum(rowSum)`

Moreover, I would like to consider *several* (e.g., 7) matrices satisfying the same conditions.

**EDIT:**
I have tried to write the code and completed the one part of it. The code is:

```
x=rand(21,50,7);
for k=1:7
    cons=max(x(:,:,7));
    for i=1:50
        for j=1:21
            if x(j,i,k)==cons(i)
                x(j,i,k)=1;
            else
                x(j,i,k)=0;
            end
        end
     end
 end
 x
```

Comment: It's unethical to write your thesis code for you; it may (according to the rules of your institution) be unethical for you to ask us to write your code for you.  You'll find, though, that SO loves a trier, so write as much of your code as you can and ask again for help in ironing out the bugs.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: It depends very much on the part of the thesis. If this was to become the core algorithm of a thesis titled "an algorithm for distributing numbers in an array", then yes, it's unethical. If instead, the question relates to, say, creating code to simulate input for testing the analysis code the thesis is about, it's perfectly fine to ask for help.

Comment: ..I  have  tried to write the code and completed the one part of it code is x=rand(21,50,7);
for k=1:7
        cons=max(x(:,:,7));
        for i=1:50
            for j=1:21
                if x(j,i,k)==cons(i)
                    x(j,i,k)=1;
                else
                    x(j,i,k)=0;
                end
            end
        end
end
x
Now i am trying to implement other condition on it.Your little effort will be the great help to me..

Comment: @VijaySaini I've embedded your code in your question. Please don't post code in comment in the future.

Comment: @VijaySaini - what is the status with this question? are you happy with the answer you got?

Comment: @Shai- no,I am not satisfied with this answer,do you have any other answer.

Comment: @Shai- what will be the code if nCol==sum(rowSum).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would not always be possible to construct a binary matrix that satisfies your requirements.
Suppose you want a binary matrix of size `nRows`x`nCols` with `rowSum` (a vector of length `nRows`) `rowSum(k)` the number of `1`s in `k`th row.
So, if `nCol ~= sum( rowSum )` it would be impossible to construct such matrix: you would either have columns with no `1`s, or columns with too many `1`s...

Therefore, your binary matrix is completely defined through `rowSum` - up to random permutation of its columns.

How about this function to construct the basic matrix `b`:

```
function b = makeBizarreBinaryMatrix( rowSum )

nRows = numel( rowSum );
nCols = sum( rowSum );   
rows = 1:nRows;
rowInd = zeros( 1, nCols );
rowInd( cumsum( [1 rowSum(1:end-1)] ) ) = 1;
rowInd = rows( cumsum( rowInd ) );
b = sparse( rowInd, 1:nCols, 1, nRows, nCols );
```

Now you can use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to randomly permute the order of the columns:

```
nb = b(:, randperm(size(b,2)) );
```

Good luck with your thesis.

Comment: It's unethical to write code for someone working on a thesis.  Shame on you.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: The OP has actually rendered it into a valid question now, and as remarked earlier, the code is not very likely to be a major part of the thesis. Writing someone's thesis is unethical. Asking for help on the details of a thesis sure isn't; you could even argue that *denying* help is unethical. I'll +1 the -1, because it's simply undeserved.

Comment: I've now removed my downvote from this answer in response to OP's editing of the question. I'm pleased to see that my harshness has prompted OP to post some code.

Comment: @Shai "harshenss" is always "harsh"... otherwise it's not "harshness" :)

Comment: @Shai That still doesn't make any sense. Anyway, I think my fatigue is talking... :)

Comment: @VijaySaini - the code I posted is for the case `nCol == sum(rowSum)`

Comment: @Shai-The answer code having `rowInd = rows( rowInd )`is not returning any value coz subscript indices must be real value.